# Time read out another table Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have one Function in postgresql. And now I have fixed data in my code.

Here one piece of my code:

```sql
"TimeStamp_data" > now() - interval '100 hours');
```

How is it possible to get the 100 hour read out from another table?

Example:
Table: Times
Column: cg_time.

So i like to read out from the cg_time column the time. So enough just change in the table, not need to change in the code.

Comment: Use `make_interval(hours => cg_time)`

Comment: Yep, just join the other table according to the desired logic.

Comment: Thank you for the help.
This solution make_interval(hours => cg_time) not working sadly. When run the query get error   " ERROR: function make_interval(minute => integer) does not exist "

Comment: Psql ask me to cast. The now() of corse Timestamp, and the cg_time is int4. That should be problem?